# How to convert the dictionary to dataframe in this format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
dic = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'x': ['y', 'z', 'w']}
```

Then I would like to convert `df` of the form

[image]

This conversion is repeated many times. Could you please elaborate on an efficient way to do so?

Comment: So what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) it:

```py
dic = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'x': ['y', 'z', 'w']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df.melt(value_name='node', var_name='root')
```

```
    root node
0   a    b
1   a    c
2   a    d
3   x    y
4   x    z
5   x    w
```

---

**Edit:** To handle uneven node lengths, create the original `df` explicitly [**`from_dict`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with index orientation, which will pad the uneven nodes as `None`. Then `dropna` at the end:

```py
dic = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'x': ['y', 'z', 'w', 't']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index').T
df.melt(value_name='node', var_name='root').dropna()
```

```
    root node
0   a    b
1   a    c
2   a    d
4   x    y
5   x    z
6   x    w
7   x    t
```

Answer (score 3):

use `melt`

```
d = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'x': ['y', 'z', 'w']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).melt(var_name='root',value_name='node')

print(df)

  root node
0    a    b
1    a    c
2    a    d
3    x    y
4    x    z
5    x    w
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over your `dict` and create the data that your want.

```py
import pandas as pd


dic = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'x': ['y', 'z', 'w']}

column = ('node', 'root')
data = [(node, root) for root, nodes in dic.items() for node in nodes]

d = pd.DataFrame(columns=column, data=data)

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
  node root
0    b    a
1    c    a
2    d    a
3    y    x
4    z    x
5    w    x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

you're giving the data frame a `.csv` extension, and naming it `test.csv`